# Ordinary should be made a synonym of penny farthing or vice verse

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag for ordinary should be made a synonym for penny farthing or vice verse. Technically, ordinary is the correct bike geek term but most people know them as penny farthings.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/penny-farthing/synonyms  Has been added, needs some upvotes.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has the potential to cause confusion. Will the non-bike geeks who arrive on the site misuse the ordinary tag?

Comment: @jimchristie it's not likely to be very common, as it's not an obvious tag.  We can always retag if it happens

Answer (score 2):

Try tagging something with a synonom ("ordinary" in this case) and the SE backend will put in the root synonom tag.  Note its not a bidirectional link.

[image]
<sup>Can't post images in a comment, sorry</sup>

---

Update - this has been approved and is now live.